# Ag Grid- Angular 5: multiple column edit using startCellEditing()

Tags: angular5, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have implemented `onStartEditing()` in `ag-grid` angular5 to make the multiple column editable. When I click on the edit button the fields becomes editable. But if i click on any rows the editable mode changes.

### html

```
<button  class="editButton" id="editButton"(click)="onStartEditing($event)">EDIT</button>
```

### .ts

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this.***.gridOptions && this.***.gridOptions.api) {
      this.***.gridOptions.api.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: i,
        colKey: 'xxx',
      });
      this.***.gridOptions.api.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: i,
        colKey: 'xxx',
      });
    }
  }
```

What i want is to retain the editable mode even I click on any rows in the grid.